# How to convert sympy boolean to python normal boolean？

Tags: python, sympy

sympy use it's own `True/False` type (i.e.`true/false`) as the result of judgement, which is not allowed to addition.
For example,

```py
(x>2).subs({x:2})+1
```

this script is not allowed. Is there any simple way to replace it？like，convert the type back to the normal python bool？

Comment: can't you just wrap your expression as `bool(sympy_expr)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it with `bool()` to get a Python boolean.

Or if you want something that is more symbolic, you can use `Piecewise((1, x > 2), (0, True))` instead of `x > 2`.